# Add comment link to a view

Tags: views

I created a new content type (News). I then added a new node.  After doing these, I created a 'view' of the node. In the view I added the "Add comment link" as a field.

I have the following issues:

1. In the "Add comment link" settings of the View, if I do not select the "Show teaser-style link" option, the link does not appear on the view page.
2. When I select the "Show teaser-style link", the "Add comment link" appears on the page as expected. However, the link redirects to the original node page.

What I would really like to do is show the 'full node form' on the view page without it redirecting to the original node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render full node change the view settings as follows

In your view change the FORMAT settings as follows

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In this format, please how can i add and position a field like the "Share this Link"? Also how do I add the post date since it is not normally displayed in the node. Thanks again.

Comment: @seyi If you have other question please make it as another post. BTW, Can you try the above answer? is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried your answer and it works (the comment field now appears). But i do not know how to display some fields in this format. When i was using the 'fields format', i could display all kinds of fields related to the node.

Comment: @seyi what is 'share this Link'? did you install ShareThis module? or is this  a custom link?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to change the view's format from "fields" to "content". Then you can activate the comments in the format settings.

Also, you then have the option of displaying the entire node (with or without links to the original node page).